# What the difference: mapnik and mapnik2?

Tags: installation, mapnik, ubuntu, osm2pgsql

I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTC, postgres 9.1, postgis 2.0.

I install mapnik.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mapnik/nightly-trunk
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install libmapnik mapnik-utils python-mapnik
```

Which version of mapnik I install? https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/Mapnik2
in this documentation write that mapnik may be 0.7 or 2.1

```
>>> import mapnik
>>> mapnik.mapnik_version()
300000
```

In synaptic: 3.0.0+dev20130906.git.f3b8645-1~precise1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mapnik 2 is a major change release.  There have been many updates and alterations that mean backwards compatibility is not guaranteed.  [See the documentation for the differences between Mapnik and Mapnik2](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/Mapnik2_Changes).  If you haven't previously used Mapnik, then I would recommend starting with version 2 to take advantage of the improvements and avoid problems later on.

Comment: Also, be sure to use a stylesheet for mapnik 2. The old ones will not run with the current version anymore.